# Why isn't Collections.binarySearch outputting consistently

Tags: java

so I am trying to write a program for school.  the point of it is to make a list of CDs that the user has in their collection.  the program needs to show the list of CDs both in their original order (CDS) and in an alphabetically sorted order (CDSS).  the information has to be stored in an array list. I also have to make the used able to add and remove programs.

when I when I enter the song "Beatles - Abbey Road", I assumed it would output a 1 from the collections.binarySearch, but instead it outputs -1 two times then it outputs 1's.  it seems to work for the other songs though.

I also cannot remove a song as it creates an error

thanks for the help

```
private void buttonInitializeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    //this is where the original songs are added(when the initialize button is pressed)
    Collections.addAll(CDS, "Metric - Fantasies", "Beatles - Abbey Road", "Pearl Jam - Ten", "Doors - Alive", "The Rolling Stones - Gimme Shelter");
    Collections.addAll(CDSS, "Metric - Fantasies", "Beatles - Abbey Road", "Pearl Jam - Ten", "Doors - Alive", "The Rolling Stones - Gimme Shelter");
    //once the initialize button is pressed the other buttong will be able to be enabled
    buttonDisplay.setEnabled(true);
    buttonRemove.setEnabled(true);
    buttonAdd.setEnabled(true);
    buttonInitialize.setEnabled(false);
}                                                

private void buttonDisplayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    outputSongList.setText("Original Order");

    int condition = 0;
    //condition is the value thatis increased by 1 every time each of these while loops are ran. 
    //from 1 to however many objects there are in the either the CDS or CDSS array list
    //the extra S in CDSS stands for sorted
    while(condition < CDS.size()){
        outputSongList.setText(outputSongList.getText() + "\n" + CDS.get(condition));//writing the contents of the array list to the text area
        condition++;
    }
    outputSongList.setText(outputSongList.getText() + "\n\n\nSorted Order");

    Collections.sort(CDSS, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);//this sorts the CDSS array in alphabetical order

    condition = 0;

    while(condition < CDSS.size()){
        outputSongList.setText(outputSongList.getText() + "\n" + CDSS.get(condition));//the same as the previous while loop
        condition++;
    }
    buttonDisplay.setEnabled(false);//disables the display button so the user knows that all information is displayed
}                                             

private void buttonAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String inputSong = enterSong.getText();//getting the string that the user typed into the enterSong text field

    if(Collections.binarySearch(CDS, inputSong) < 0){//this checks if the inputted song is in the arraylist
        CDS.add(inputSong);                             //if it is, the outputted number will be 1...i thought
        CDSS.add(inputSong);                            //if it isn't the numer will be less than 0
        Collections.sort(CDSS);              //this if statement will run if the inputted song isn't already in the arrays
        buttonDisplay.setEnabled(true);                 
    }
}                                         

private void buttonRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String inputSong = enterSong.getText();

    if(Collections.binarySearch(CDS, inputSong) > -1){//if the inputted song is in the array this line will run
        CDS.remove(Collections.binarySearch(CDS, inputSong));
        CDSS.remove(Collections.binarySearch(CDS, inputSong));
        buttonRemove.setEnabled(false);
        buttonDisplay.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've said, `CDS` is not sorted in any particular order.  `Collections.binarySearch` states clearly in its Javadoc that it only works if the list it receives is already sorted.

Instead of using `Collections.binarySearch`, you will have to use `CDS.indexOf(inputSong)` and accept the linear search.